# how to display data from json with looping javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.5

[This is my json code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07lm7.png)

This is my javascript:

```
$('#kurir').change(function(){
var kurirID = $(this).val();    
if(kurirID){
    $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"{{url('checkout/kurir')}}?kurir_id="+kurirID,
       success:function(res){               
        if(res){
            $("#ongkir").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#ongkir").empty();
            $("#ongkir").append('<option>--- Pilih Kurir ---</option>'); $.each(res,function(key,value){ $("#ongkir").append('<option value="'+key['service']+'">'+this.value['service']+'</option>'); }); }else{ $("#ongkir").empty();
        }
       }
    });
}else{
     $("#ongkir").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#ongkir").empty();
    $("#ongkir").append('<option>--- Pilih Kurir ---</option>');
}});
```

This is my controller

```
public function getKurirList(Request $request)
{$data = RajaOngkir::Cost(['origin'=> 419,'destination'=> 114,'weight'=> 1700,'courier'=> 'jne',])->get(); return response()->json($data); }
```

I want to show all "service" data and price "value".

How to iterate this json with a 'each' loop and print the data?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what have you done ?

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over  `$datas['0']['costs']`

```
foreach ($datas['0']['costs'] as $key =$value){

  echo $value['service'] . ' - ' $value['cost'][0]['value']; 


}
```

Comment: @TaufanAdiBriyanto  is better if you post a new question properly described .. looking the code in  comment is not easy and in this way all the SO comunity  could help you  .. when you have posted  the new question you can comment me the related  link

Comment: as i suggested in the comment before... is better if you   post a new question  ..  PHP is not javascript and there are user that know better than me javascript